# How to read data from the Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read data from a particular node from the firebase realtime database.
This is my JSON tree:

```
{
  "user" : "1",
  "user_details" : {
    "emails" : [ "valker@gmail.com" ],
    "usernames" : [ "valk stone" ]
  }
}
```

How do I read data from the user node?

Comment: What does the Firebase documentation say on this? What did you try?

Comment: Hello, Thomas. I saw that I could add a child event listener but it only gets triggered when any thing get added, removed and changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data with the help of listener. If you read [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) you come to know that `SingleValueEvent`is used for read data once :

```
ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("user_details");
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);
```

Comment: Hello Ashish, but this is a value event listener. How will this know that I only want to read the user node.

Comment: if you see variable `databasereference`. you just have to change the reference to path of database node you want to read

Comment: @Jandroid so does this helps you ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot!